# Compile Actionscript From Vim

Tags: vim, actionscript, compilation

I switched to Vim from Textmate a while back but I miss the Actionscript bundle for Textmate—particulate the ability to compile Actionscript directly from Textmate.

Has anyone found a way to compile Actionscript directly from Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, compiling AS3 from Vim is very easy.

One basic way, assuming you have `main.as` file open and you are in `--NORMAL--` mode, type this:

```
:!/path/to/flex45/bin/mxmlc %
```

to obtain `main.swf` file next to `main.as` or:

```
:!/path/to/flex45/bin/mxmlc -output=../deploy/%<.swf %
```

to obtain `../deploy/main.swf` (relative to `main.as`).

- `!` means "the following is a shell command".
- `%` means "this file, here, in the current buffer".
- `%<` means "this file's name without the point and the extension".

Obviously it's not really smart but you can make `mxmlc` read a configuration XML, for more control. See the Flex doc for the list of possible arguments. Using this way it's going to suck a lot to debug your builds.

Another way is to set `mxmlc` as the build program for actionscript files with:

```
set makeprg=/path/to/flex45/bin/mxmlc
```

Then, type `:make %` to build your project. Errors will be displayed in the quickfix window.

That said, the actual "programming" part of doing AS3 with Vim sucks hard because [the only omni-completion script available](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2478) (to my knowledge) has been very very limited and unfinished for years (it's not an attack against the author which must be praised for his efforts).

I've started to augment that script a couple of months ago but it's far from being finished (and a low level priority) and not that good anyway compared to what you may get in Flash Builder or FDT.

Actually, the AS3 bundle is the only thing I miss from my TextMate days, it was surprisingly polished.

Answer (score 1):

In the official vim documentation, there is an topic called: ["fcsh tools : you can compile .as and .mxml files from vim via fcsh : Flex Comipler SHell"](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1793). That topic describe all process of compilation *.as* and *.mxml*, but as noticed there, it tested only on unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use FCSH on vim, take a look on https://github.com/lucasdupin/vim-utils/blob/master/bin/fcshd - it works exactly like the FCSH daemon you have on TextMate.